# Como pegar informações do sistema operacional do servidor?

Tags: php, servidor, sistema-operacional

Como eu posso obter o sistema operacional do meu servidor? Por exemplo, algum método para saber se o sistema operacional do ambiente de produção está em Linux, Windows, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem algumas maneiras que você pode utilizar para obter esta informação:

### [php_uname()](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.php-uname.php)

O `php_uname()` retorna informação sobre o sistema operacional que o PHP foi construído.

```
echo php_uname(); //Windows NT I5 6.1 build 7601 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition Service Pack 1) AMD64
```

Para verificar se o sistema operacional é Windows, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
$so = explode (" ",php_uname());

if($so[0] == "Windows"){
  //Windows
}else{
  //Não Windows
}
```

### [PHP_OS](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.predefined.php)

Pode utilizar `PHP_OS`, uma constante pré-definida também, em que [retornará a maioria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738823/possible-values-for-php-os) da famílias de sistemas.

```
echo PHP_OS; //Linux
```

Para verificar se o sistema operacional é da família operacional do Windows, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
if(PHP_OS == "WINNT"){
        //Windows
    }elseif(PHP_OS == "Linux"){
        //Linux
    }...
```

Ou pode fazer assim ainda:

```
<?php
  if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
    // Windows
  }else{
    // Não Windows
  }
?>
```

---

Você pode ver uma [lista mais completa de resultados na Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname#Table_of_standard_uname_output) ou nesta pergunta respondida no nosso [Grande Irmão SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/738893).

#### Nota

Como dito nos comentários também existe as [variáveis superglobais $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). Apesar de ter testadas (em um servidor de produção) uma a uma e elas somente retornarem outras informações relacionadas ao servidor, (nenhuma retornou o sistema operacional) elas podem ser úteis em algumas outra situação.

Abaixo este script [encontrado na documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#111471) que retorna *praticamente* tudo relacionado às variáveis `$_SERVER`:

```
<?php 
$indicesServer = array('PHP_SELF', 
'argv', 
'argc', 
'GATEWAY_INTERFACE', 
'SERVER_ADDR', 
'SERVER_NAME', 
'SERVER_SOFTWARE', 
'SERVER_PROTOCOL', 
'REQUEST_METHOD', 
'REQUEST_TIME', 
'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT', 
'QUERY_STRING', 
'DOCUMENT_ROOT', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE', 
'HTTP_CONNECTION', 
'HTTP_HOST', 
'HTTP_REFERER', 
'HTTP_USER_AGENT', 
'HTTPS', 
'REMOTE_ADDR', 
'REMOTE_HOST', 
'REMOTE_PORT', 
'REMOTE_USER', 
'REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER', 
'SCRIPT_FILENAME', 
'SERVER_ADMIN', 
'SERVER_PORT', 
'SERVER_SIGNATURE', 
'PATH_TRANSLATED', 
'SCRIPT_NAME', 
'REQUEST_URI', 
'PHP_AUTH_DIGEST', 
'PHP_AUTH_USER', 
'PHP_AUTH_PW', 
'AUTH_TYPE', 
'PATH_INFO', 
'ORIG_PATH_INFO') ; 

echo '<table cellpadding="10">' ; 
foreach ($indicesServer as $arg) { 
    if (isset($_SERVER[$arg])) { 
        echo '<tr><td>'.$arg.'</td><td>' . $_SERVER[$arg] . '</td></tr>' ; 
    } 
    else { 
        echo '<tr><td>'.$arg.'</td><td>-</td></tr>' ; 
    } 
} 
echo '</table>' ;
```

Comment: Eu incluiria na lista o array global [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) que também contém informações do servidor.